# How do I get the execution plan for a view?

Tags: mysql, performance, execution-plan, view

I have a schema with a number of views.  I need to check the execution plans to make sure the appropriate indexes are in place and being used.

How do I do this?

I'd rather not have to copy and paste the output from `show create view <viewname>` into `explain`, especially as some of the views are built on top of other views and this would be quite a pain.

Comment: Note that the execution plan may be different when the VIEW is used in real-life queries, as it depends on the WHERE and other clauses in the query selecting from the VIEW. Although MySQL is fairly bad at optimizing VIEWs, it does have some optimizations where conditions are pushed down for example.

Comment: @Jannes good point, I didn't consider that aspect.  Is it safe to assume that the execution plan from `select * from <view_name>` will match?

Comment: Yeah as far as i know. If you want mysql to use an index on field1 in *select * from <view-name> where field1=10* then you have to keep the view really simple. No GROUP BY or UNION for example. I guess you could say the execution plan you are looking at is sort of the worst case situation in that it could only get better if mysql finds an optimization to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I first tried:

```
mysql> explain view_name;
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| field1  | varchar(3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field2  | varchar(3) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| field3  | bigint(21) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| field4  | bigint(21) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+---------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Obviously this doesn't work -- it's the same as doing `describe view_name`.

However, `select * from view_name` seems to work:

```
mysql> explain select * from view_name;
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived5> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   18 |                                 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  105 | Using where; Using join buffer  |
|  5 | DERIVED     | <derived6> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   68 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  6 | DERIVED     | basetable  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  928 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | DERIVED     | <derived4> | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  386 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  4 | DERIVED     | basetable  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  928 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: +1 for a clearly, simpler answer. I adjusted my answer based on yours. You should accept your answer on this one.

Answer (score 8):

Use the [**information_schema.views**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/views-table.html) table

This will generate the EXPLAIN for all views

```
mysql -uroot -p -AN -e"select concat('explain ',view_definition) from information_schema.views" > /root/ExplainViews.sql
```

This will generate the EXPLAIN for all views in the mydb database

```
mysql -uroot -p -AN -e"select concat('explain ',view_definition) from information_schema.views where table_schema = 'mydb'" > /root/ExplainViews.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

### **UPDATE 2012-03-22 11:30 EDT**

@MattFenwick, your answer is a whole lot simpler than mine. Here is an example I tried out on my PC running MySQL 5.5.12. I ran EXPLAIN on both the SELECT version from your answer and the EXPLAIN generated from my answer:

```
mysql> explain select * from bigjoin;
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | k     | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL          |   14 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.k.id_key |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          |    4 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> explain select `a`.`id_key` AS `id_key1`,`b`.`id_key` AS `id_key2` from ((`test`.`idlist` `k` left join `test`.`id_key_table` `a` on((`k`.`id_key` = `a`.`id_key`))) left join `test`.`new_keys_to_load` `b` on((`k`.`id_key` = `b`.`id_key`)));
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref           | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | k     | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL          |   14 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | test.k.id_key |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL          |    4 |             |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+---------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

They both produced the same EXPLAIN plan. I will change my answer to implement your way. You get a +1 from me although it's +2 for simplicity. You should go ahead and accept your own answer on this one.

Here is an interesting factoid about VIEWs in MySQL : A view is represented in two places in the information_schema database

- [**information_schema.views**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/views-table.html) : table_schema,table_name identify, and view_definition
- [**information_schema.tables**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/tables-table.html) : table_schema,table_name where ENGINE is NULL

This will generate the EXPLAIN for all views

```
mysql -uroot -p -AN -e"select concat('explain select * from ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') from information_schema.tables WHERE engine IS NULL" > /root/ExplainViews.sql
```

or

```
mysql -uroot -p -AN -e"select concat('explain select * from ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') from information_schema.views" > /root/ExplainViews.sql
```

This will generate the EXPLAIN for all views in the mydb database

```
mysql -uroot -p -AN -e"select concat('explain select * from ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') from information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='mydb' AND engine IS NULL;" > /root/ExplainViews.sql
```

or

```
mysql -uroot -p -AN -e"select concat('explain select * from ',table_schema,'.',table_name,';') from information_schema.views WHERE table_schema='mydb';" > /root/ExplainViews.sql
```

Comment: +1 for showing that the execution plan is the same both ways!